# File ended while scanning use of \@LTRfootnotetext

Tags: errors, texstudio

I use text studio to write a latex file in Persian. It worked good and produce the output pdf using xelatex. I edited the file and now when I want to compile it it produces

```
File ended while scanning use of \@LTRfootnotetext.
```

However, it shows no line number. It also give warnings for my citations, probably because it can't find the bibliography part. It could be due of any unbalanced braces. But in so many footnotes and other stuff, how can I detect it? Any solution or software that can automatically do this?

Answer (score 0):

The unclosed brace was in one of my last sections like `LTRFootnote{\lr{something}`. To detect it I noticed the sections and chapters after this section are not displayed in the panel of `Structure`. So this hint can be useful to detect the section containing the problem.